# Some doubts about how to set the height of a div to prevent its contents come out from it

Tags: html, css, layout, xhtml

I have some little problem setting the right height of some informative boxes.

If you go in this example page you can simply understand what my problem is: http://onofri.org/example/example3/test2.html

As you can see under the **Main Report** area I have 3 boxes.

The problem occurs in the boxes titled as **Links** and in **Work Supported by Japanese Trust Found**

As you can see these boxes contain some informative text. The problem is that if I enlarge the character (in the browser, using <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>) this informative text goes out of the box (it goes out of the bottom of the box)

Is there a way to solve this problem? I want that box always contains its content.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `min-height` property to set the height. This allows the boxes to "grow" when needed.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/43MjD/4/

Comment: mmm can you give me a litle example about it? where have I to set the min-height property? and why?

Tnx

Comment: @AndreaNobili sure, let me get a jsfiddle up :)

Comment: but in this way you are not using the min-height propery but only the height property...so I can set an height property to the div (that create my box) but if later I enlarge the font in the browser, the text come out again...

Comment: @AndreaNobili look at the 2nd box, "#content-fluid". the first one is displayed for comparison.

Comment: I have find this solution and seems to work fine: http://www.esperto-seo.com/siti-internet/css-come-adattare-laltezza-di-un-div-contenitore-al-suo-contenuto

Comment: @AndreaNobili in that case create a new answer and accept that answer :)

Comment: Andrea, the solution in the page you linked is exactly what @wei2912 suggested you to do...

Answer (score 1):

Don't give the div a height so the box will expand as the text does.